# Object reference not set to an instance of an object-datacontext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, deployment, datacontext

I am trying to publish asp.net mvc site on remote server I am getting the error as shown in figure. Any idea
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the problem was that in the designer file connection name was different then that of web.config. Once both name are same it started running fine.

Comment: Glad you sorted the problem. Please set your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could post a larger scale of the image, the stack trace is very tricky to read.

As a guess, it looks like the exception is being raised in the database context area of code - possibly Entity Framework??

First, have a look at the `Models.EvloetDatabaseContext` constructor - is there anything in there that might cause the null reference exception?

You could put some `Trace.WriteLine` calls in that method and use a tool such as [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to see how many of those messages are being sent out. I use his often when debugging issues on a client's server.

Comment: Try opening the image in a new tab. :) **Edit:** I reformatted it so that you can click through to the image.